# Can I have priority passed back to me during spell resolution, so that I can do more with my own spell?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack, mtg-priority

So, this is a basic question, but I want to make sure I'm getting this right.

Suppose I have a [Lightning Bolt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLightning%20Bolt%5d) and a [Twincast](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTwincast%5d), and I want to bolt my opponent twice.

I know that to do so I can do the following:

- Cast lightning bolt.
- Hold priority.
- Copy it choosing a new target.

Now, what I want to know is if I can cast lightning bolt, pass priority, and then, after checking if my opponent has a response for it, copy it. Like:

- Cast lightning bolt
- Pass priority.
- Oponnent passes priority back without putting anything else on the stack.
- Copy lightning bolt.

Is the forth move illegal? My spell resolves right after my opponent passes priority, without I having a second chance to put more stuff on the stack?

Comment: What makes you think that you might have an additional priority after your opponent passes priority?

Comment: @murgatroid99 tbh I've been uncertain about this too, because I haven't had rule 608.1's full implication spelled out for me like below. it's good to see this asked about.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I thought this was a space to ask things I was uncertain about, sorry if I misunderstood the goal of this site.

Comment: It wasn't my intention to imply that this question doesn't belong. But in many cases, knowing the reason for asking can inform better answers. That's why I asked. I'm sorry if it came across as criticism or dismissive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you wait for your opponent to respond and your opponent has no response, your lightning bolt resolves before you can twincast it.

> **608.1**. Each time all players pass in succession, the spell or ability on top of the stack resolves. (See rule 609, “Effects.”)

You'll only get a chance to copy the bolt if they respond, or if you cast both spells before passing priority the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Each object on the stack, each phase (except Untap), and each step have this exchange of players passing priority. It is commonly referred to as "APNAP" or "Active Player and Non-Active Player." The active player is the player who is currently taking their turn. Whenever a phase or step is entered, any abilities from cards that try to go on the stack will do so, and then the active player will gain priority. The active player will hold priority until that player passes.

If, for some reason, you as the Active Player have 100 mana and 100 1-mana instant spells in your hand, you could cast them, one after another, in response to each of your spells, for example. Then, once you decide to pass priority after the last ability or spell is put on the stack, your opponent would have priority for that very last spell which tries to resolve FIRST. After it resolves or leaves the stack, the next spell would try to resolve and you would gain priority again until passed to your opponent.

Comment: APNAP refers to situations when multiple players need to do something st the same time (2 triggered triggering on the same event; etc).

Comment: Indeed it does.

More closely, it is only called "APNAP," not "APNAPAP" or "APNAPAPNAPAPNAPAPNAPAP" etc. etc. The active player receives priority once, then the non-active player receives priority once, and then that's it.